# EEG instrumentation amplifier stage

Tags: amplifier, noise, eeg

I am trying to design an amplifier for EEG SIGNAL using INA 126(gain 6.5). I've included for you the attached schematic diagram.  The simulation was working but  When I tried to implement the  circuit on a breadboard, I got a very high EEG sensor voltage at the input port which was driving my amplifier to saturation. Tried without the bias return path also. It also gave the same result.  Help me figure out where I am going wrong. The green color denotes EEG input at the INA 126 AND Yellow colour denotes the output of amplifier.

[image: schematic]

[image: i/o signal]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. from your question I am not sure if you are describing a problem with simulation or physical circuit.

The data sheet for the AD623 (the part in the simulation schematic) lists the absolute maximum supply voltage as 12V, either 0-12V single ended, or +/-6V dual supply. You appear to be applying 18V (+/-9V), which is well outside the valid supply range

Comment: thank you for the reply. Sorry, I shared the wrong schematics.  I was using INA 126 and not AD623. I am facing problem with the physical circuit

Comment: Are you probing with the return lead connected to your circuit ground? Otherwise you will see large 50 Hz common mode noise, just as is visible

Comment: What happens when you don't have that cap on the output??

Comment: @jithin Please write a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your circuit. Try touching your oscilloscope probe with your fingers while touching the ground with the other hand and look what you get.

You will probably see all sorts of noisy garbage but with the highest amplitude peaks occurring at the frequency of the AC outlet voltage for your region. And you'll probably be surprised to find that this noise has an amplitude more than a volt, or hundreds of millivolts if you're lucky.

All of that is real. Have you ever touched the prong of an audio input cable hooked up to an amp? Or just try it with your desktop speakers if you have some. When touched, you'll hear a quite loud 50 or 60Hz hum come out of the speakers.

You are a meat-based capacitor and the dielectric material, your skin, has a great deal of surface area. The electric fields from the wiring in your house and whatever else is near you couples into your body's capacitance and the result is you have as close to, if not more than a volt of AC across various parts of your body pretty much all the time.

Your instrumentation amplifier is dutifully amplifying these signals by the high gain you've set and of course saturates.

Long story short, you cannot measure EEGs or any other bioelectrical signal with nothing but an amplifier alone. You need to add something called a **right leg driver.** This is essentially an active version of your reference electrode that attaches somewhere distal from your electrodes measuring the signals of interest. It doesn't actually have to be to the right leg of course, left legs are almost as popular and the chest would be fine for an EEG, though one of the ankles would probably be even better.

What this electrode does is actively force your skin to the reference potential of the instrumentation amplifier, thus canceling out (or attenuating by ~100 fold at least) all that common mode noise on your skin and allowing you to measure the much weaker signals of interest, like those from the brain.

It is, for all intents and purposes, just a virtual ground buffer, but it is driving you, the forbidden capacitor, as that ground.

In your circuit, this might replace the reference electrode like so:
[image]

However, it is usually better to ground the reference pin and instead try to cancel out the common mode noise directly, as it appears across the gain resistor with a low pass filter in series with each gain resistor pin, like this:

[image]

Unfortunately, simply using a reference electrode is totally insufficient to quiet the noise environment of a person's skin.

**Note**: Schematics are not complete, power connections and decoupling was omitted. They are only meant to demonstrate the concept.

Comment: Your top RLD circuit has a cap in the feedback loop and no resistor.

Comment: Also, just split the gain resistor in two, and take the feedback from there.

Comment: FWIW, RLD feedback can buy you about 20dB, and was real important before modern high-CMRR inamps, but you should certainly be able to see a signal of appropriate gain without it (so long as the subject's reference electrode is appropriate).  Low gain would have not much to do with RLD

Comment: “*Unfortunately, simply using a reference electrode is totally insufficient to quiet the noise environment of a person's skin.*” This is simply false.